# C# Extension for Parsing JSON Like Power Query Extension

Tags: c#, json, .net, parsing

Was wondering if there is an equivalent to Power Query out there in C# land that can be imported to a .NET application so that I can consume JSON API and parse it without having to write a parser for ever type of API I'd like my app to be able to consume. For example, the Power Query helps excel, Power BI etc Windows Apps to setup the API to consume the JSON then the user walks through the steps for parsing so that it can refresh seemlessly. Any ideas on this help would be appreciated.

Comment: Power Query is actually implemented in .NET (mostly, with some wrapping around unmanaged libraries for some connectors), so it is possible to use the assemblies, with a bit of reverse engineering, if you've built the M query elsewhere. I don't necessarily recommend going down this path, since it's quite nontrivial and likely involves violating the license agreement, but I happen to know (somehow, ask no questions) that it does work. Beyond this, though, asking for library or tooling recommendations is off-topic for SO.

Comment: Use punctuation and break up the sentences, it is difficult to read.